# .htaccess RewriteCond specificity

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to remove my index.php file from urls. I have a RewriteCond set to ignore certain files and folders. My problem is, I need to ignore a directory named "test" but the condition, as currently written, also ignores anything that starts with the letters test, so my "testimonials" directory is also ignored. Is there a way that I can make my RewriteCond more specific, so it will ignore "test" but not "testimonials"?

Here's my existing code:

```
# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|assets|test|index\.php|info\.php|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|assets|\/test\/|index.php|info.php|robots.txt) [NC]